# Tableau: Invalid dates range shown in the filters, specified range does not get set

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, dashboard

I have a Due Date column in the data source and set a filter to this specified range.**(2/3/1996 - 12/31/2050)**. I changed the type by **(Right click -> Change Data Type -> Date)** option in Dimensions.

But after I try to move the slider and change the range, it gets reset to a different range which I did not specify.

[image]

**Sample data is as below:**

```
Entity Code Customer Name   Currency    Region  Entity Country  Day_of_Week Due date
      12354         KELLY        EUR        ABC     Spain          Thursday 8/10/2017
      80921         BRONK        EUR        TOZ     Spain            Sunday 7/23/2017
      34578         SMITH        EUR         TX     Spain            Sunday 10/8/2017
```

Comment: What language are you using ? Please edit your question and add the relevant tags, as well as some sample code that can be usefull to help.

Comment: @MartinVerjans It's a dashboard that I'm developing using 'Tableau' with no programming code. It's just regarding setting up parameters and range values.

Comment: Show the data... need to check how exactly your data is?

Comment: @Siva I have added the sample table.

Comment: So Due date was in string format and now you have changed it to Date format and filter showing wrong values... is that correct?

Comment: Tableau read string date accurately even your format as well. what you need to check is, select a single date by adjusting slider anywhere. then pull date in the sheet and check format matches or not.let me know  in case  pattern in the sheet appears to be wrong or similar to filter

Comment: Their are few observations here, If the data you provided is correct (Due Date) then tableau should convert the datatype as expected, Else you need to recheck whether you have changed the datatype of Entity code instead of due date or due date format is not `DD/MM/YYYY` instead it will be in numeric format like `Entity Code`. Post your observations for further advice